# Sorting objects in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a function `urlScores` which return an array of object in the form

```
[{"url":"facebook","score":2},{"url":"reddit","score":1},{"url":"stackoverflow","score":3}]
```

I am asked to sort this array in regards to its score **using bubble sort**.

What I have tried doing is creating a bubble sorting function that takes the object returned from `urlScores` and sorts it.

```
function sort(object)
{
  for(var i=  0; i < object.length; i++){
    if (object[i].score > object[i+1].score) {
      var temp = object[i]
      object[i]=object[i+1]
      object[i+1]=temp
    }
  }
}
```

And the function that should be called for sorting the array looks like:

```
function rankedScores(web,pattern)
{
  return (sort(urlScores(web,pattern)))
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working, I am faced with `TypeError: object[(i + 1)] is undefined`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: When you say a[i] .. What is a ?

Comment: Error caused because you have passed the index you have to check index of last element. Array works on -1 index from 0,1,n

Comment: Samay, edited it the post, thank you.

Comment: Karman, for(var i=  0; i < object.length-1; i++) works in fixing the error. However, the output is undefined.

Comment: I have updated the function. I guess you should not use object as variable name as it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @Pete I have posted the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected your sort function.

```
function sort(a) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i].score > a[i + 1].score) {
            var temp = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i + 1]
            a[i + 1] = temp
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Here is an example

```
var arr= '[{"url":"facebook","score":2},{"url":"reddit","score":1},{"url":"stackoverflow","score":3}]';

console.log(sort(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var a = [{"url":"facebook","score":2},{"url":"reddit","score":1},{"url":"stackoverflow","score":3}];
 
function bubbleSort(a)
{
    var swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if (a[i].score > a[i+1].score) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}
 
bubbleSort(a);
console.log(a);
```